# CBS, Capes and Pigeonholing?

Tags: comic-adaptation, the-incredible-hulk-tv, the-amazing-spider-man-tv, wonder-woman-tv

For Comic-book to live action adaptations, the 1970's presents a few notable milestones of which Today's Superhero Media empires lineage can be traced.

Remarkably, CBS retains the highest pedigree for this period, commissioning (or in the case of *Wonder Woman*, picking up from another network) a variety of licensed characters to be developed into TV. This is the channel which created *The Incredible Hulk*, *The Amazing Spider-Man* and the above mentioned Wonder Woman all within the period of a few years.

All three have lasting pop cultural legacies (even if Spider-Man is for all the wrong reasons), and yet according to Lou Ferrigno's (The Incredible Hulk himself, no less!) autobiography, the channel ultimately canned all three projects so as not to be pigeonholed "The Superhero Channel".

Is there any evidence, outside Ferrigno, to support this? It seems lunacy to be so short sighted and eradicate all three properties in one decision; particularly when the licensing rights could have been sold to other channels, as CBS themselves had done with *Wonder Woman?*

Comment: If you can't accept an industry insider like Lou as proof, there will never be an answer to this. Private details of corporate inner workings rarely have public evidence. Then again, look at Sci Fis recent pigeonhole idiotic stance towards wrestling and mockumentary like ghost hunting, things they went with to get away from the Sci fi pigeonhole.  Like a bunch of morons.